# Best low-end Mac for iPhone game development?

Tags: iphone, mac, applications, hardware-recommendation, android

I am a freelancer who mostly works on developing websites and other video editing stuff. I want to move into iPhone app development, but I am unable to decide on which Mac I need to buy. I'm looking at the 13" Macbook Pro (Intel Core i5 with the integrated graphics)?

- Will this machine be able to fulfill the requirements?
- Can I use the same machine for Android app development?
- And is this x86?

Comment: Welcome to AskDifferent. Unfortunately shopping advice for hardware is off-topic, as specified in the [FAQ]. I suggest you visit a local retailer and explain your needs for a better advice.

Comment: Of course it's x86 - it's an Intel CPU, and they only make x86.

Comment: You should look at a Mac Mini, best mac for cost comparison.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to Ask Different!

If you're wanting to do video editing, web design and software development on the move, I'd personally say that a 13" screen is too small. I'd go for the MacBook Pro 15".

However, you can connect a MacBook Pro to an external display when working at a desk which would allow you much more working space for your applications.

In terms of performance, I'd say that the machine should be able to cope pretty well with everything you want to do. I'd maybe look into the exact graphics requirements for the type of video you're editing just to make sure that the Intel HD graphics are up to it.

This machine's processor has an x86-64 instruction set - so yes, x86 compatible. It can run both 32 and 64 bit applications and Operating Systems.

There is an Android SDK available for Mac OS X as well as a whole host of IDEs. Macs can also run Windows if necessary, so I'm pretty confident that you'd be able to get all the tools you'd need.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to be doing Video Editing "stuff" you may be happier with macbook pro 15".  the 13" is a great machine for just developing, but for video editing, depending on the video editing software, you'll be best served with a macbook pro 15" with a discrete video card.